# Date to DateTime in app engine cloud endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the cloud endpoint api built in java using Objectify (https://github.com/objectify/objectify/). The model class have a field

```
import java.util.Date;
private Date updatedAt;
```

But after the android client library is generated, I can see that this particular field is changed into

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
private DateTime updatedAt;
```

Can anyone please explain this? And how to convert from one to another without losing timezone information?